# Apache CFX OAuth and Spring Security Exception in Glassfish

Tags: netbeans, oauth, spring-security, glassfish, cxf

I have problem. I would like to implement OAuth with Apache CFX 2.75.  There is a sample  named "oauth" (server and client) directory  in "Apache CFX 2.75".[Apache CFX WebSite][1]
I make it run on Jetty , but i would like to move  both client and server samples to Glassfish and Netbeans. Everything  is fine and working , But only final step  "/auth/resources/person/get/john" and "/auth/resources/person/modify/john" gives  500 code and error is

```
 "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" .
```

when i debug the sample code both in glassfish and jetty ,
in *"demo.oauth.server.spring.SpringOAuthAuthenticationFilter"* class , 
line 51==>

```
   "List<String> authorities = (List<String>)request.getAttribute(OAUTH_AUTHORITIES);"
```

returns empty list  in Glassfish.
But in Jetty , return  roles ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN. 
It does not set attribute "OAUTH_AUTHORITIES".
I could not solve the problem , what it should be in Glassfish ? I does not change anything in code or in xml configurations.

Can you give me advice please ?

**NOTE : All code is a sample in this link ==>"[Apache CFX 2.75][2]" . Only i add "sun_web.xml" to deploy project to Glassfish.**

http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-275-release-notes.html

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/cxf/2.7.5/apache-cxf-2.7.5.zip

Comment: on your glassfish : do you have any cluster or is it a standalone instance ?

Comment: no i dont,  it is a standalone istance.

Comment: I try all them on local , If i try to deploy to glasswish without changing in code , It does not work only at final step. The final step is in demo.oauth.server.SampleResourceProvider class. @willome